# ASP script to find keywords from Search

Tags: search, asp-classic, keyword

I'm looking for an ASP script that can parse a referral string from a search engine and extract just the keywords from it. I know this can be done using PHP, but I happen to working on a website that uses ASP.

Can this be done using ASP? Or, would it be better to find a Javascript/jQuery version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can be done in Classic ASP. E.g.:

```
<%

Dim i, url, querystring, keywords

url = Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER")

If url <> "" Then
    Response.Write "Referrer: "
    Response.Write url
    Response.Write "<br>"

    querystring = Request.ServerVariables("QUERY_STRING")

    If querystring <> "" Then
        keywords = Split(querystring, "&")

        If IsArray(keywords) Then
            For i = 0 To UBound(keywords)
                Response.Write keywords(i)
                Response.Write "<br>"
            Next
        End If
    End If
End If

%>
```